# Clearing output if input is changed

Tags: winforms

I have two text boxes on my form. The first text box calculates an amount when it is clicked and the amount total is displayed in the second text box. I'm trying to create an event handler that will clear the text in the second text box if the value entered in the first is changed. 
For example, You can only go on the ride if you are 5 years old. The user enters 5 in 1st text box. The second text box displays "You can ride!". Now if the user changes the number 5, I want the "You can ride!" to be cleared. 
I don't have any code, because I'm not sure which text box you create an event handler for, the one that takes input or the one that displays the output. Does anyone have any suggestions or what I can search on Microsoft's page to know more about clearing? The only thing I was about to find so far was this example: `textBoxName.Clear();` but I'm not sure where to put that. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: You probably want the [TextChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged?view=netframework-4.8) wired up to your input textbox.

Comment: I want the 2nd text box to be cleared *only* if the input in the 1st text box is changed. I tried checking out TextChanged event for the 1st text box like you mentioned but it shows a drop down menu of the calculate and exit button on my form, it doesn't show anything related to the other text box.

Comment: @rythm500 you would use the [TextChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.click) as @JSteward mentioned. I'm not sure what you mean when you talk about a drop down menu of buttons on your form. `TextChanged` is the default event for a `TextBox`, so just double-click your first `TextBox` in the designer and writhe the code in the empty function it generates.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `TextBox.Clear Method` to clear the text in a TextBox.

The following is a simple example to determine whether the value in TextBox1 is "5" and modify the value in TextBox2 in real time.

The demo uses [Int32.TryParse Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Int32__) to detect if the value in TextBox1 is a number.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int number;
    bool success = Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out number);
    // input is a number
    if (success)
    {
        // if input is 5
        if (number == 5)
        {
            textBox2.Text = "You can ride!";
        }
        // else clear TextBox2
        else
        {
            textBox2.Clear();
        }
    }
    // input is not a number, re-input
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
    {
        // Clear wrong input
        textBox1.Clear();
        MessageBox.Show("Please input a number!");
    }
    // input is empty
    else
    {
        textBox2.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ideally, one would post a non-intrusive "banner message" somewhere near the input box (akin to those "you have caps lock / num lock on" appearing on the login screen) rather than a modal pop-up dialog—as "text changed" events are triggered on literally all text changes, but otherwise the answer is good for the current familiarity with GUI programming the OP ostensibly has.